# How to lock double-click to variation in WooCommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and YITH Color and Label Variations for WooCommerce plugin.

I have a problem with my website. When I access "[Link website](http://test.com/)" then the price is display. And I click (uncheck) black color then the price is hidden.

I want to remove or lock it so that users cannot use the double-click to variation(color or size).

I have research a lot but cannot solve it. Looking forward to your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some CSS trick to lock the option.

```
.select_box_colorpicker .selected { pointer-events: none; }
```

Please check and let me know if this works.
Thanks!